# Is there anyway to exclude website logo from 'og:image'?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am looking for a way to exclude website logo image from `og:image`. Because,

> When I share a link on Facebook, it [preview the correct thumbnail image of the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW44f.jpg) but shows [logo image when link is posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAzTt.jpg).

I am using these `Meta Tags` for social media thumbnails.

```
<meta property='og:image' content='<?php echo $thumb; ?>' />
<meta property='og:image:secure_url' content='<?php echo $thumb; ?>' />
<link rel='image_src' href='<?php echo $thumb; ?>' />
```

If I [post the same link after removing logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RS7o.jpg) from the site, **it works fine**.

I figure out, it is Logo Image that is creating problem for me in sharing my links on social media.

Please let me know, If somehow I can able to exclude website Logo.png image from `og:image`.

I am using wordpress Newspaper 11 theme. I don't know whether the theme has an issue or something else.

Comment: There is no way to "exclude" anything here. If you don't _specify_ any `og:image`, _then_ Facebook will analyze the rest of the page content, and pick an image they think might be suitable. But if you _do_ specify it, then Facebook will use the specified image - as long as it can read that image URL without problems.

Comment: @CBroe, Did it bro Did it. Through rank-math plugin (https://i.imgur.com/9SjX4JU.jpeg), but still did work.